# Issue with an early Euler problem in C - why am I getting output "nan"?

Tags: c, nan, fibonacci

Maybe a small problem for this forum, but here goes:

The ProjectEuler.net problem #2 is as follows:

> By considering the terms in the
>   Fibonacci sequence whose values do not
>   exceed four million, find the sum of
>   the even-valued terms.

Why am I getting "nan" output?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fiblist[] = {0,1};
long double sum = 0;

void fibonacci(){
  int i = 2;
  while (fiblist[i] < 4000000){
    fiblist[i] = fiblist[i-1] + fiblist[i-2];
    i++;
  }
}

void main(){
  fibonacci();
  int i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i != '\0'; i++){
    if (fiblist[i] % 2 == 0)
      sum += fiblist[i];
  }
  printf("%Lf \n", sum);
}
```

Comment: Did you notice that the even ones are every third one in the sequence?

Comment: You don't need the whole array of Fibonacci numbers, just use two variables for the current and previous numbers! Also you can check if a number is even in the first loop.

Answer (score 4):

**while (fiblist[i] < 4000000){**

At this point, you haven't actually assigned anything to **fiblist[i]**.

(Also, unrelated, but why do you need a double, if you're only working with integers significantly smaller than 2**31?)

Comment: There are several other bugs too.  For instance, there is only memory allocated for two elements of `fiblist`.

Comment: Well, yes, but that was the most obvious one, and also the most relevant to the question "why am I getting NaN?"

Comment: Yes, I agree.  Just wanted to provide a clue for the next bug he'll encounter. (-: